# How can i override the value of form submitted in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am saving the form in the view like this

`form.save()`

but before that i want to set the datetime field to now.

something like

`form.timestamp = datetime.now`

how can i do that

Answer (score 3):

Better way:

Change the field in your models.py using `auto_now_add` and `auto_now`:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True)
```

In this way, every time you save your form, your field gets updated.

Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield).

Comment: i get this error-- date should be in this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]` . how can do that

Comment: Did you have other data with another formatting inserted in your database?

Comment: i am editing the existing code , so i think it may be the case. but what should i do

Comment: I didn't mean your code but your entries in the database. If you're using a test database, delete that database and python manage.py syncdb.

Comment: Actually i can't delete the data , how cani make the current format equal to the format in database

Comment: If you're really really sure that is the source of your problem, you can change it using South http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app

Comment: By the way, when do you get that error? When you're doing runserver or when you try to insert a new record?

Comment: when i try to insert new record

Comment: Oh, right. Then it's more likely your code. Sorry, I thought it occurred when you restarted your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.timestamp = datetime.now
instance.save()
```

JD

Comment: Those are my initials.. they aren't part of the code block. Above is how you would override any of the fields in your form that you would like - rather than using an auto_add which is just for the dates, and uses a field that will not show up on your form.